# Obtain the full configuration of a service including its parameters

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

`php app/console container:debug` does not give enough information on the services.

### 1 - What parameters are injected during the creation of a service?

If I want to know what parameters are injected into the service `form.factory` for example, is there a command for this?

`php app/console container:debug form.factory` does not give the list of parameters.

### 2 - Is there a way to find the location of a service (meaning the file where it actually is declared)?

It could be either:

- a `services.yml` file
- a `services.xml` file
- through the `DependancyInjection\Configuration.php` file

But which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What parameters are injected during the creation of a service?

This does not exists yet, however I have planned to create a Pull Request for this for Symfony2.2

> Is there a way to find the location of a service (meaning the file where it actually is declared)?

No and you won't get a feature like this. The code is not able to get the location of the file.

What you can do is locate in which bundle where the service is declared. All services from the core framework are declared in the SymfonyFrameworkBundle. You can find the service configuration in `@bundleroot/Resources/config`. The `form.factory` service is loctated in `@SymfonyFrameworkBundle/Resources/config/form.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDebuggingBundle

It partly answers to your needs, by dumping dependencies of a given service.
However, it does not says where a service has been defined.

Comment: Great @Florian! This bundle is great!